# Finding the mean with an upper triangular matrix

Tags: r

How do you calculate the mean of the elements of "concordance" by row (not considering the values equal to 1 or 1.0):

```
x=matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0),4,5)
ncolumn=dim(x)[2]
concordance = matrix(1,ncolumn,ncolumn)
concordancevec = rep(0,(ncolumn*(ncolumn-1))/2)
for (i in 1:(ncolumn-1)){
        y=t((t(x[,i])))
        z=x[,(i+1):ncolumn]
                for (j in 1:(ncolumn-i)){
                m=(t(t(z)))
                        concordance[i,j+i] = mean(y*(m[,j])+(1-y)*(1-m[,j]))
                        concordancevec[i*j] = mean(y*(m[,j])+(1-y)*(1-m[,j]))
                }
        }
concordance
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you the row means (which is what you seem to want):

```
> sapply(1:4, function(i){mean(concordance[i,-(1:i)])})
[1] 0.4375000 0.4166667 0.6250000 0.7500000
```

`1:4` are the rows in the upper triangular part, and for any such row `concordance[i,-(1:i)]` is the part of the row that you want to take the mean of. Simply apply the function which takes these means to the vector `1:4`.

It is even easier to get the overall mean of the upper-triangular part:

```
> mean(concordance[upper.tri(concordance)])
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for :)